# To Explode or RewriteRule? Utilizing Variables From Hyphenated URL's

Tags: php, regex, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I'm hoping I can make this make sense.

I had URLs' that looked like this

http://www.website.com/state/AZ/Phoenix

And now I've written them to this

http://www.website.com/AZ

using this rewrite code to parse (borrowed)

```
 RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
 RewriteRule ^([^/.]+)(?:/)?$ /x.php?state=$1 [L]
 RewriteRule ^([^/.]+)/([^/.]+)(?:/)?$ /x.php?state=$v1 [L]
 RewriteRule ^([^/.]+)/([^/.]+)/([^/.]+)(?:/.*)?$ /x.php?state=$1&city=$2 [L]
```

This works great for parsing the "AZ" portion of the url and using it as a variable. Awesome. However, I wanted to take this to the next step and start using the city, and even crazier? not in the same order.

DESIRED URL FORMAT: http://www.website.com/phoenix-arizona-other-words

NOTE: I understand this doesn't say "AZ", it's fine, I'll convert the state to abbreviation through an array - the more important part is grabbing the first two words, separated by a hyphen and assigning them to variables.

For my code to work correctly I'll need to either find a way to explode the "-" in the URL and assign variables this way...

```
//my terrible attempt at fixing this the HARD way
$variables  = explode("-", urldecode(substr($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'], 1)));
$city       = isset($variables[1]) ? $variables[1] : false;
$state      = isset($variables[2]) ? $variables[2] : false;
```

or...

A RewriteRule could possibly save the day and understand what to do with the newly formatted URL and allow x.php? to utilize the correct variables, all while keeping the desired website.com/phoenix-arizona structure.

I think I'm close, basically, I need a Rewriterule to recognize hyphens and assign them to specific parameters, however I've been searching and tinkering around for over 4 hours on this before finally giving in! Any help would be appreciated, and if I'm not thinking about this correctly, it wouldn't surprise me as it's quite clear my regex (RewriteRule) skills are rudimentary at best and the explode function, if it even works, might be total overkill.

Comment: what about Salt Lake, or a city with hyphens in its name? (for example, Sedro-Wolley in Washington)

Comment: wow, that's a great point. I guess I can do it with a /, but even trying that my current code doesn't work. Thanks for bringing that up.

Comment: Ok. What are the rewrite rules supposed to do?  Because  [^/.]+ means "everything that is not a slash or .", but unescaped . Is a wildcard, so that turns into "everything that is not a slash or any other character". I bet that's not what you meant.

Comment: I'm not sure, I borrowed the rules from another thread and it did what I needed for allowing the url website.com/AZ to be used like x.php?state=AZ.

Answer (score 0):

ok. I'll try to complete this answer tomorrow. But for the first rule, you might try with

```
RewriteRule ^([A-Z]){2}/? /x.php?state=$1& [L,QSA]
```

This means: match exactly two uppercase characters from A to Z, followed by an optional trailing slash and whatever comes next

This will turn

```
http://www.website.com/AZ
```

into

```
http://www.website.com/x.php?state=AZ
```

AND

```
http://www.website.com/AZ/whatever-url
```

into

```
http://www.website.com/x.php?state=AZ&whatever-url
```

Note that I have appended @anubhava QSA flag to append any query string after the slash to the rewrite rule. I could have captured that part with a wildcard (.*) too. I like his way more than mine.

States are easy because thanks to the USPS they all have kinda standard two character codes.

**Edit: now for the second rule**

```
RewriteRule ^([^-]+)-([^/-]+)- /x.php?statelong=$2&city=$1& [L,QSA]
```

will turn

```
http://www.domain.com/tucson-arizona-whatever-comes-next
```

into

```
http://www.domain.com/x.php?statelong=arizona&city=tucson&whatever-comes-next
```

Note that I inversed the captured items so I pass the second one to `statelong`. This way on your PHP you'll know that the state name needs to go through your dictionary array to get its standard USPS 2 character code.

Again, the "whatever comes next" gets appended thanks to the QSA flag. You'll need to capture that part with php by printing out the `$_GET` superglobal and looking for the orfan key.

Now, what happens when you get

```
http://www.domain.com/new-york-new-york-these-vagabond-shoes
```

Of course the rule won't work. Besides, the song was written when there was a New York County, roughly equivalent to today's Manhattan. (Irrelevant trivia).

**The next is just an idea. I'm sure you can come with a more creative way**

You need a way to tell cities from states from rest of the url. One way to do it is to use underscores to separate composite names, comma to separate city from state and hyphen for the rest.

This rule

```
RewriteRule ^([\w_]+),([\w_]+)- /x.php?statelong=$2&city=$1& [L,QSA]
```

will turn

```
http://www.domain.com/new_york,new_york-this-vagabond-shoes
```

to

```
http://www.domain.com/x.php?statelong=new_york&city=new_york&this-vagabond-shoes
```

Comment: Ok, thanks. The state I have down pretty good with existing code, but this is definitely cleaner. The cities might be a bit more difficult, unless I use a / and ignore all "-" and then just strip the hyphens for use.

Comment: Edited. Good luck with your URLS.

Comment: Thanks for the help, however I didn't get it to work in any capacity for what I needed, so I took most of the code I had and then parsed the URL to do what I needed using a /. I did like your idea about underscores, and I would like to implement that but I couldn't get that to work either.

Answer (score 0):

This rule should work to translate your `PHP` code into a `rewrite` rule:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^([^-]+)-([^/-]+)-(.+)$ /x.php?state=$1&city=$2 [L,QSA]
```